# Nested bash command not working in teamcity ssh exec

Tags: bash, ssh, teamcity

I'm trying to write a script to restart my server in teamcity using the "SSH EXEC" type build step.

One of the things the script has to do is unzip a zip file I upload in a previous step, but the version in the filename will always change, so I'm trying to lookup the name of the zip using a nested command.

```
unzip `ls | grep zip`
```

This works for me when I ssh to my server and do it in the terminal, but it doesn't work when teamcity tries to do it.  I get the following message in the build log

```
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] 
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] 
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -p  extract files to pipe, no messages     -l  list files (short format)
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -f  freshen existing files, create none    -t  test compressed archive data
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -u  update files, create if necessary      -z  display archive comment only
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -v  list verbosely/show version info       -T  timestamp archive to latest
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -x  exclude files that follow (in xlist)   -d  extract files into exdir
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] modifiers:
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -n  never overwrite existing files         -q  quiet mode (-qq => quieter)
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -o  overwrite files WITHOUT prompting      -a  auto-convert any text files
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -j  junk paths (do not make directories)   -aa treat ALL files as text
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -U  use escapes for all non-ASCII Unicode  -UU ignore any Unicode fields
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -C  match filenames case-insensitively     -L  make (some) names lowercase
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -X  restore UID/GID info                   -V  retain VMS version numbers
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -K  keep setuid/setgid/tacky permissions   -M  pipe through "more" pager
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -O CHARSET  specify a character encoding for DOS, Windows and OS/2 archives
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   -I CHARSET  specify a character encoding for UNIX and other archives
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] 
[19:36:55][Step 3/3] See "unzip -hh" or unzip.txt for more help.  Examples:
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   unzip data1 -x joe   => extract all files except joe from zipfile data1.zip
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   unzip -p foo | more  => send contents of foo.zip via pipe into program more
[19:36:55][Step 3/3]   unzip -fo foo ReadMe => quietly replace existing ReadMe if archive file newer
[19:36:56][Step 3/3] SSH exit-code [0]
```

Comment: Why not just `unzip *.zip`?

Comment: I also am using this nested command style to execute other commands.  So I would still like to know why the nested commands aren't working.  Thanks though for the info!  I didn't know unzip could take a regex

Comment: Wildcards are expanded by the shell, they work for every command automatically.

Comment: It's not a regexp, it's a wildcard AKA glob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what unzip outputs when there are no arguments. My guess is that `ls | grep zip` is returning an empty string because ls didn't find anything.

I think this is an artifact of how the local shell processes the string input to ssh. When you do

```
ssh $host "unzip `ls | grep zip`"
```

from a local bash shell, bash sees that there is an embedded subshell and first executes `ls | grep zip` locally, and embeds the result into the string, and passes the resulting string to ssh. Since (presumably) there is no zip file in the current directory where this ssh command is executed, the actual command passed to the remote shell becomes

```
ssh $host "unzip "
```

The way to fix this is to escape the backquotes so they are not interpreted by bash, but embedded and forwarded to the remote shell:

```
ssh $host "unzip \`ls | grep zip\`"
```

Comment: Or `ssh $host 'unzip $(ls | grep zip)'`. Single quotes prevent bash from interpreting anything